# When are default node attributes set during a chef client run?

Tags: chef-infra

I edited sample code to clarify my issue. I think the answers make more sense now since my first recipe is indeed inside a ruby_block.

When are default node attributes available during a client run? Let me clarify. My example is simplified, but what I'm trying to do is more complex than this, but the concept is similar.

I bootstrapped a node, which ran with an empty run list. So far so good.

Now I add my hello_world cookbook to my node's run list.

```
knife node run_list add node_name "recipe[hello_world]"
```

In my hello_world cookbook, I have the following default attribute defined in attributes/default.rb

```
default.hello_world.location = ''
```

I have a recipes/default.rb that does this

```
include_recipe "hello_world::set_location"
include_recipe "hello_world::show_location"
```

recipes/set_location.rb does

```
ruby_block "Set location" do
  block do
    node.set.hello_world.location = "New York!"
  end
end
```

and recipes/show_location.rb does this, using the log resource

```
log "Hello #{node.hello_world.location}"
```

Should I expect to see this in the chef-client run...

```
Hello New York!
```

...or simply this, since the cookbook has not completely run yet and therefore its attributes have not been sync'ed with the Chef server?

```
Hello
```

I am getting the latter, that is, just "Hello" without "New York!"

How can I get my cookbook to log "Hello New York!" after its client run?

That is, in general, **how can I set node attributes in one recipe so I can use them in a different recipe of the same cookbook during a chef-client run?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading of chef is described [here](http://docs.chef.io/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run) and the attribute precedence is described [here](http://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence)

You should have the expected result as you're updating the attribute value before the log resource is compiled, because the node.set is not in a ruby_block.

I suspect the use of method syntax to be the problem, prefer using the hash access.

i.e:

```
node.set['hello_world']['location'] = "New York!"
```

and

```
log "Hello #{node['hello_world']['location']}"
```

But as it's not real code (if I understood correctly) I can't swear it's the real case, without a real case I can't be sure why you get this result.

You may use [lazy evaluation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-attribute-evaluation) in other context (attribute updated within a ruby_block)

Comment: These are equivalent: node.set.hello_world.location = "New York!" and node.set['hello_world']['location'] = "New York!" I will look at lazy evaluation.

Comment: @ChrisF Is it a real "test cookbook" or is it an example based on your actual problem ?

Comment: It's an actual cookbook I'm having issues with. The concept is similar though

Comment: Similar is my reason to doubt, if the attribute is changed in a resource (ruby_block for exemple) it will give your actual output

Comment: Tensibai you are absolutely correct. I edited my sample code. Thanks!